# What is the opposite of static?

Tags: c#, terminology

I was just wondering what is the opposite of static? Im looking for a word or terminology to describe it.

eg:

```
#region Members

#region Static

private static Settings _Instance = null;

#endregion Static

#endregion Members

#region Properties

#region Static

/// <summary>
/// Gets the current instance of the settings class
/// </summary>
public static Settings Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_Instance == null)
        {
            _Instance = new Settings();
        }

        return Settings._Instance;
    }
}

#endregion Static

#region Non Static?

#endregion Non Static?

#endregion Properties
```

If Im seperating my code in to static and non-static regions what should I call my non-static region?

is it non-static? or is there an actual word to descripe methods and properties that are not static

Comment: In English, "dynamic," but that opens a whole big can of worms.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

"Instance" usually - "instance methods", "instance variables" etc. Non-static works too, if you find that simpler.

I'm [not sure I'd really put all those regions in though](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/the-problem-with-code-folding.html)...

Comment: ah of course, had a bit of a mental block there. I dont generally have lots of regions but its helpful for me to split them by static and instance. thanks. and interesting read :)

Comment: I would't say "instance" since a static variable can be an instance of something. Could be confusing.

Comment: @Filip: I think the term "instance variable" is reasonably unambiguous, isn't it? Just because the value can refer to an instance doesn't really confuse that, IMO.

Comment: I agree, but I was rerfering to only saying "Instance". i.e. "This is not static, this is an instance".

Comment: What about dynamic? (not a suggestion, more of a question)

Comment: @David: Well, it's related - but in a somewhat academic way, and only with respect to *some* members - those which can be declared as `virtual` basically, and overridden in derived types. Those members behave "dynamically" - but this isn't the same as the kind of dynamic you get through the `dynamic` type.

Comment: @JonSkeet which language's syntax are you referring to when you use 'instance', 'virtual', 'member' and 'dynamic'? I'm a Java --> Ruby guy, but those terms ultimately like they come from C. Ruby, of course, uses 'instance' extensively which is mainly the way I understand the usage of the word.

Comment: @David: It's not part of the language *syntax*, but it's part of the terminology defined in the C# spec - this being a C# question.

Comment: `#region` is one of the best things! It's the major reason I prefer using Visual Studio over any other editor like Eclipse. When my file is getting 1000+ lines big I hit a key and open the correct regions to get to the code part I want to edit and I never have to scroll to search for the method. Using `#egion` is the same as organizing your files in several folders, no regions = **all** your files in 1 folder.

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki: No, because it's not the *members* that can be instantiated. The members are *related* to instances.

Comment: Why? I can say: "Static classes are not instantiable and the others are"

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki: Yes, that works for classes. Now what about fields, and methods, and properties?

Answer (score 4):

**Non-static** would be correct. The word "instance" is more commonly used to describe a particular occurrence of a object or class in memory.